# How to accurately add extrinsic balance transfer values

Tags: polkadot-js, balances

Is there a simpler way to add balance transfer values without converting them to BN or Unit value first? For example, say I want to add "0x00000000000000001bc16d674ec80000", "0x000000000000021e19e0c9bab2400000" and  "0x00000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000" which in units are "2.0000 Unit",  "10.0000 kUnit", and "1.0000 Unit".

I have used [@polkadot/util](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@polkadot/util) 's `formatBalance` with `forceUnit` option to get uniform units and then add. But I feel like there may be a better way.

Answer (score 8):

I'm assuming the above are hex strings? In that case you would need to convert and add them.

```js
import { hexToBn } from '@polkadot/util';

// convert and add
const total = hexToBn('0x00000000000000001bc16d674ec80000')
  .add(hexToBn('0x000000000000021e19e0c9bab2400000'))
  .add(hexToBn('0x00000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000'));

// format as needed
```